# translate SQL into LINQ (IN (SELECT) statements)

Tags: sql, linq

I need to convert sql query into LINQ (query syntax) but I'm stuck on IN statement.

How can I write LINQ for this WHERE clause on my sql query:

```
WHERE OR_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT OR_ID 
                FROM OR_ORDER_WORKER_HISTORY owHist 
                WHERE CLIENT_RATE_ID = @clientRateId)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where(x => db.OR_ORDER_WORKER_HISTORY
    .Where(owHist=> owHist.CLIENT_RATE_ID == clientRateId)
    .Select(owHist=> owHist.OR_ID)
    .Distinct()
    .Contains(x.OR_ID))
```